# Printing a structure

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I want to print a Sudoku on my terminal and I got this structure :

```
#define SUDOKU_SIZE 9
typedef struct {
  int grid[SUDOKU_SIZE][SUDOKU_SIZE];
} sudoku_t;
```

And I got this in my main function :

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
   sudoku_t *s;
   s->grid[0][0]=6;//manualy setting the value of the sudoku
   ...
   s->grid[8][8]=7;
   int k, l;
   printf("\n");
   for(k=0;k<SUDOKU_SIZE;k++){
       for(l=0;l<SUDOKU_SIZE;l++){
           int a=s->grid[k][l];
           printf("%d", a);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

There is no problem during compilation, but I got a "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" error during execution.

Thank you

[EDIT]
Ok, I used malloc, and used free at the of my function,
but I still get an error : *** Error in `./ingis': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001e8d010 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

Here's the updated code :

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
   sudoku_t *s=(sudoku_t*)malloc(sizeof s);
   if(NULL==s){
       perror("malloc() failed");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   int k, l;
   printf("\n");
   for(k=0;k<SUDOKU_SIZE;k++){
       for(l=0;l<SUDOKU_SIZE;l++){
           int a=s->grid[k][l];
           printf("%d ", a);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n");
   free(s);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You don't allocate any memory for `s` before you assign `s->grid[0][6]`.

Comment: Did any text get outputted before the core dump?

Comment: Change your pointer to a struct into an non-pointer variable: `sudoku_t s;`, and you should be fine.

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled: I get warnings related to your problem when compiling.

Comment: Just replace `sudoku_t *s;` with `sudoku_t *s = (sudoku_t *) malloc(sizeof(sudoku_t));`
[Demo](http://ideone.com/t5SdJr)

Comment: As a general advice: use the `-g` flag when compiling and call `gdb ./yourprog` afterwards. Then type `run` into the gdb prompt. When the program crashes, gdb should show the line the error occured in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the definition here

```
sudoku_t *s;
```

the `s` is pointing nowhere.

So dereferencing it like here

```
s->grid[0][0]= ...
```

tries to read invalid memory, and with this invokes undefined behaviour. Anything can happen from this moment on.

To fix this just define a `soduko_t` and not just a pointer to it by doing:

```
soduko_t s;
```

and replace all `->`-operators by a `.`.

Alternatively you could allocate memory dynamically be doing

```
 soduko_t * ps = malloc(sizeof *ps);
 if (NULL == ps)
 {
   perror("malloc() failed");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

After the code is done using `s`, free the memory:

```
free(ps);
```

Comment: Okay, I understand, but when I make the free() call, I got this error : free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000217f010 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: @Cariamole: Just *add* your updated code to the bottom of your answer, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @Cariamole: Err, you need to free if you allocated using `malloc()`. Do not do `sudoku_t s; .... free(s);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for the struct.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  sudoku_t *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
  s->grid[0][0]=6;
  // continue...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a pointer like `sudoku_t *s;` just declare it as a normal variable `sudoku_t s;`

And now just use the `.` operator instead of the `->` operator like

```
s.grid[0][0] = 6;
...
s.grid[8][8] = 9;
...
int a = s.grid[k][l];
```